# Value of type '(UIButton) -> ()' has no member 'setTitle' in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift3

I have been creating an idle clicking game/application. The way you purchase upgrades is by clicking a button within a table cell. What I can't figure out, is how do I set a title for a button (I want to have price listed on each button). When I try I get the error, **"Value of type '(UIButton) -> ()' has no member 'setTitle'"** I'm using Xcode 8.2, and Swift 3.

Custom Cell Controller:

```
@IBAction func upgradePurchase(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if GlobalVariables.sharedManager.balance >= GlobalVariables.sharedManager.UpgradesPrice[GlobalVariables.sharedManager.UpgradesCurrent] {

    }
}
```

TableView Controller:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    let row = indexPath.row

    let showPrice = "Buy: $\(GlobalVariables.sharedManager.UpgradesPrice[row])"

    cell.upgradeIdentifier.text = GlobalVariables.sharedManager.UpgradesName[row]

    cell.upgradeDescription.text = GlobalVariables.sharedManager.UpgradesDesc[row]

    cell.upgradePurchase.setTitle("\(showPrice)", for: .Normal)

    GlobalVariables.sharedManager.UpgradesCurrent = GlobalVariables.sharedManager.UpgradesPrice[row]

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Which line is giving that error? And post the declaration of your `CustomTableViewCell` class (specifically the outlets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By mistake or accidentally You are trying to set the title for button Action not to the `UIButton` instance. Here `upgradePurchase` is `IBAction` not the `IBOutlet`.

You need to set the title to your `IBOutlet`, so make one if it is not then set the title.

```
cell.btnupgradePurchase.setTitle("\(showPrice)", for: .normal)
```

**Note:** In Swift 3 it is `.normal` not `.Normal`.

Comment: @AidenR. Welcome mate :)

Comment: @DownVoter Please at least care to add reason of down voting the answer.